# Recursively delete small files PHP script

Tags: php, file

How to recursively delete small files, smaller than 10 kilobytes regardless on their creation time, format or name?

PHP script needs to go through cache folder and all sub folders and delete files smaller than 10 KB. It would be nice to show list of deleted files, but it is not must. Also it would be nice if script can be set via cron job, but also it is not must, it can do manually too.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please indicate what you've tried so far so people can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into things such as the readdir function and unlink would be a good start for this project.

Comment: I am searching for php script which will do it for weeks, but nothing. Also I am not php programmer, so I tried to find already made script or some very similar to what I need, but nothing like that.

Comment: Ah.  Sorry I don't know any pre-made php scripts that do this either.  My guess would be that you would have to create it yourself.  The good news is that php is a fairly simple language and google has lots of examples for things.  Also this site can really help out if you get stuck on any part of it.  My suggestion would be to try and create it yourself because I don't think you'll find one that does what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. Hopefully I will find or make something.